Tedious Type Casting when indexing Vectors in Rust
Im currently trying to optimize my code for readability and have run into issues when I'm indexing an array but also need to use negative number. Here's the example:
Example Case
Explanation since its difficult to read:
This code is trying to go over every element in the vector and find the elements to the left and right of it. The right one is subsequently subracted from the left one and printed as output. If at any point an index is out of bounds it is replaced with 0
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mask = [-1, 1];
    
    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        let l_index = (i as i32 + mask[0]);
        let left = if l_index >= 0 {vec.get(l_index as usize).unwrap_or(&0)}
        else {&0};
        
        let r_index = (i as i32 + mask[1]);
        let right = if r_index >= 0 {vec.get(r_index as usize).unwrap_or(&0)}
        else {&0};
        
        println!("Sum: {}", *left as i32 - *right as i32);
    }
}

Expected result:
Sum: -2
Sum: -2
Sum: 2

This code isn't an actual part of my code, just an example. This problem often occurs when I decide to use these 'masks' or when I'm doing linear Algebra in a 2d Grid, as you often have to subract or add possibly negative values.
The main point is, I have to do a total of 6 Type-conversions since I need support for negative numbers but also require the ability to index into an vector.
I also had to extract the index-equation into a seperate line: let l_index = (i as i32 + mask[0]);. Otherwise I would've just written vec.get(i + mask[0]).
Question
In conclusion I find this code completely illegible for anyone unfamiliar with it. This case in particular isn't for a major codebase, however I want to follow the best practices even in my own codebases. I would like to find a way to improve the readability in cases where you need both the functionality of negative numbers as well as the ability to index an array safely.
(I am very aware you can easily change how I set up the mask, however I have cases where such masks are much larger and would like to keep them simple.)
playground

You can use a wrapper around Vec (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f4826b3837f284dac44658145429b0a).

I might do something like this as a one-off: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f1913c644e498cfa5fd90c57e1d88e1 But in general, a generic function, slice wrapper, or Vec wrapper that can be indexed by isize or i32 would probably help.

Another option is having mask be an array of fn(usize) -> usize instead. E.g. let mask: [fn(usize) -> usize; _] = [|i| i - 1, |i| i + 1]; and using those functions to do the manipulation instead. That way you never have to actually store a negative number.

@cdhowie except 0_usize - 1 will panic whereas (0_i32 - 1) as usize will just return an out-of-bonds index that vec.get will ignore.

@Jmb if you want wrapping arithmatics it's better to use it explicitly rather than implicitly through a cast. I.e. just replace i - 1 with i.wrapping_sub(1) that way it's explicit what's happening.

@cafce25 yes, see the answer I posted. I used a cast in the comment to stay close to the OP.

@Ry- I actually wrote a wrapper so I could index with any integer type that implemnts try_into<usize>.
Also thanks to everyone else for the helpful suggestions!

You can avoid most of the casts and the intermediate values by using wrapping_add:
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mask = [-1i32 as usize, 1]; // or [usize::MAX, 1]
    
    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        let left = vec.get (i.wrapping_add (mask[0])).unwrap_or (&0);
        let right = vec.get (i.wrapping_add (mask[1])).unwrap_or (&0);

        println!("Sum: {}", *left as i32 - *right as i32);
    }
}

Playground

This is definitely better than the original code! However, to me the -1i32 as usize seems a bit tedious to write out, however I can just make an iter that automatically casts everything wrapping to usize!
Thanks for the response!

I decided to come up with a little Trait that allows for indexing with a TryInto<usize> instead of just usize. This simplifies the logic a lot:
fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mask = [-1, 1];
    
    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        let left = vec.get_index(i as i32 + mask[0]).unwrap_or(&0);
        let right = vec.get_index(i as i32 + mask[1]).unwrap_or(&0);
        
        println!("Sum: {}", left - right);
    }
}

pub trait Indexable<I> {
    type Item;
    fn get_index(&self, index: I) -> Option<&Self::Item>;
}

impl<T, I> Indexable<I> for Vec<T>
where
    I: TryInto<usize>,
{
    type Item = T;
    fn get_index(&self, index: I) -> Option<&Self::Item> {
        let Ok(num) = index.try_into() else {
            return None;
        };
        self.get(num)
    }
}

playground
This is similar to a wrapper but it allows for more flexiblity. You could technically even create a wrapper type around Option<&mut T> so you can change an index without bound-checks even:
vec.get_index(index as i32).and_set(3);
assert_eq!(Some(3), vec.get(index));

Simliar to the entry()-Method in HashMap. Anyways, thank you all for the great ideas!
